# Can't rebuild DB using EF Codefirst

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-express

I had a working EF Codefirst DB. I made some changes to my entities and wanted to rebuild the DB. Due to unrelated coding errors that have since be corrected it wouldn't rebuild. So I figured I could just delete the DB from SQLExpress and the let EF recreate it. However that didn't happen. Instead I now get the error.

**Cannot open database "DataAccessTest.MyDBContext" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Server\Administrator'.**

Also in the event veiwer I get the error.

**Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database.**

Which of course makes since because it isn't there. But I don't know why that would stop it from recreating the DB.

I have already tried doing it manually from the code as mentioned in the this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911329/ef-codefirst-ctp5-manually-drop-and-create-db), but it I just got the same errors.

I know that it isn't my user credentials because I loaded up another sample EF project and was able to update it just fine. I also know that it isn't my code because when I pull it down from source control to another system it works fine.

I fear I have messed up some background file that either EF or Visual Studio uses to work with a specific DB and I can't figure out how to clear it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: How was code errors failing build process related to decision to delete database?

Comment: I thought I was using EF incorrectly and that my code was actually preventing it from rebuilding, but I new that it built it successfully the first time so my line of thinking was lets just start over and I will worry about the rebuild issue later.

Comment: Are you setting a database initializer at all and if so, which one?

Comment: Other than the one @Jayantha suggested I haven't tried any other initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually deleting the DB and use  DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initializer like this. `MyDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't seem to make a difference. I got the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the physical database files created? I have a feeling you are running into an issue where there are existing database mdf and ldf files sitting in the directory. Go there and take a look.

Comment: Good thought, but doesn't appear to be my problem. I have never changed the default location for me SQLExpress instance and all of my test DBs have loaded their just fine. There aren't any files currently for my problem project in that directory. I think I may just recreate the project to see if that clears whatever is blocking it.

Comment: That works as well...it's one that burns me every once in awhile.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to change the Initial Catalog attribute in your connectionstring of Web.config. It is not a solution but works. Actual solutions to this problem are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the db that you deleted, manually create an empty database with the same name using sql server management studio.  Once EF finds a db with the name it's looking for it will be happy.