# How to return EF database to default?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

Basically I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 application using EF code first.
Now; during my testing I've inserted a lot of annoying rows in my database.

How can I revert back to the initial seed data, discarding all other rows?

Comment: Seems like this is a database question - how to delete rows.  It has nothing to do with C#, EF, ASP.Net, or Visual Studio.  Or am I missing something?  What are you using for your database?

Comment: Pardon for the plentiful amount of tags. I merely tagged with C# asp.net etc. because that's what I'm using the database for.

I'm using entity framework code first - I don't know what else to say. 

I just want to know what to include in my Seed method to remove all pre-existing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want all of the records, just drop the database. EF Code first will create a new one on the next run. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911329/ef-codefirst-ctp5-manually-drop-and-create-db)

Answer (score 0):

Manually delete the rows from your database. you can reset your ID/Primary key seed with (in SQL Server)

```
 DBCC CHECKIDENT(YourTableName, RESEED, 0)
```

in your SQL command console from Enterprise Manager/SQL Studio.

Comment: Is there no way to do it in the seed method (C#) ?
I'd like my seed method to remove all existing data before seeding.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it. I've manually purged the records and reseeded in SQL Server Studio, which seemed to do the trick. You could delete the respective tables/database, and it'll recreate itself with Code First.